# Restkit - how to link downloaded coredata objects with objects in store

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:resourcePath usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
    [WBItemSummary setupDataMapping];
    [loader setOnDidLoadObjects:^(NSArray *objects){
        NSLog(@"%@",objects);
        block(objects);
    }];
```

In this code I have loaded WBItemSummary that is store in coredata with relation on self on to many, and I need to connect previous loaded object to current loaded throw relation, how can I do this with restkit? Response objects are in different NSManagedObjectContext with fetched previous loaded object.